# Icons for JAVA Character

Tags: java

I am testing with [Java Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and I got amazing thing for me. Please check below short codes..

```
    char myChar = 9899;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(myChar++);
    }
```

When I run above codes , I saw many icons at my console . I would like to know ...

1. What are these and has full list information for them ?
2. When I use them , has any requirements (for instance : **character code 9898** may not appear on Mac OSX) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/en/#greek-coptic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Unicode Characters. See this Link For More Info.[Click Here](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html)